# Recursive formula for definite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

The integral is:

$$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/4} \tan^{2n}x\,dx$$

I'm supposed to find the recursive formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$I_{m+1}=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\tan^{2m+2}dx=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\tan^{2m}x(\sec^2x-1)dx$$

$$=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\tan^{2m}x\sec^2x\ dx-\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\tan^{2m}x\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^1 t^{2m}dt-I_m=\frac{t^{2m+1}}{2m+1}|_0^1-I_m$$

$$\implies I_{m+1}=\frac{1-0}{2m+1}-I_m$$

Comment: This does seem correct, but if I find $I_0$, which is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and then plug it into the formula for $I_1$, I get $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}$, while if I directly integrate $I_1 = \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \tan x\,dx$, I get $-\ln|\cos x| |_0^\frac{\pi}{4}$, which does not give the same result.

Comment: @Proka, $$I_1=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\tan^2x\ dx=\cdots$$

Comment: Yeah, of course. I'm sorry, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Proka Why didn't you vote up answer? ┻━┻ ︵ヽ(`▭´)ﾉ︵ ┻━┻

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n}x\,dx&=\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\tan^2 x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x(\sec^2 x-1)\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\sec^2 x\,dx+\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\,d(\tan x)+\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\,dx\\
&=\left.\frac{1}{2n-1}\tan^{2n-1}x\right|_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}}+\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \tan^{2n-2}x\,dx\\
I_n&=\frac{1}{2n-1}+I_{n-2}
\end{align}